# Kendo UI Grid : add row including variable which impact on template

Tags: jquery, grid, kendo-ui, row, kendo-grid

My question is relative to an update of my grid. Here is my current program of grid generation :

```
leTle[0] = {index : 1, tle : tleId, nom : nomChamp, estar : "", fige : tleFixe, position : positionParam, longueur : longueurParam};               

   var fige;

   if (tleFixe == "true")
        fige = true; 
   else
        fige = false;

    $("#" + theId).kendoGrid({
        columns:[{
                    field: "index",
                    title: "Index",
                    template: "<span style='font-size: 12px;' title='#= index #'>#= index # </span>",
                    width: 40
                },{
                    field: "tle",
                    title: "TLE Id",
                    template: "<span style='font-size: 12px;' title='#= tle #'>#= tle # </span>",
                    width: 100
                },{
                    field: "nom",
                    title: "Intitulé",
                    template: "<span style='font-size: 12px;' title='#= nom #'>#= nom # </span>"
                },{
                    field : "position",
                    title : "Position",
                    width : 70,
                    attributes : {
                        "class" : fige ? " " : "fondRougePale"
                    }
                },{
                    field : "longueur",
                    title : "Longueur",
                    width : 70,
                    attributes : {
                        "class" : fige ? " " : "fondRougePale"
                    }
                },{
                    field :"estar",
                    title :"Estar",
                    template: "<span class='eStar'><input class='inputeStar' disabled type='text' /> </span>",
                    width : 250
                },{
                    command: {
                        name : "destroy",
                        template: "<a class=\"btn btn-warning btn-mini k-grid-delete\">"
                                + "<i class=\"icon-minus-sign icon-white\"></i></a>"
                    },

                    title: " ",
                    width: 40
                }
        ],
        dataSource: {
          data: leTle,
          schema: {
              model: {
                  fields: {
                      tle: {editable: false},
                      nom: {editable: false},
                      estar: {editable: false},
                      longueur: {editable: fige},
                      position: {editable: fige}
                  }
              }
          }
        },
        editable:  {
            mode: "incell",
            confirmation: false
        },
        scrollable : false
    });
```

As you can see, some of my cell can be disabled if my variable "fige" is equals to false. When I try to build my grid with a basic datasource write manually, the grid is okay. Row after row, when the cell have to be disabled, they are.

Unfortunately, when I try to add rows after the construction of the grid, my variable is never including when the cells are set.

Here is the code :

```
var vgrid = $("#tleSelected").data("kendoGrid");
            var datasource = vgrid.dataSource;
            var nbLines = vgrid.dataSource.total();
            //Booleen de test
            if (fige == "true")
                tfige = true; 
            else
                tfige = false;
            var newRecord = { index : nbLines+1, tle : tleId, nom: nomChamp, estar: "", position: position, longueur: longueur, fige: tfige}
            datasource.insert(newRecord);
```

So, I am in a situation where my variables are good, but the new lines are not.

Instead of destroying my grid and rebuild them after an update of data, do you know a solution for this case ?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

This may not be exactly your answer but may help you achieve your goal. every time grid's datasource changes the `formatMe` function will be called and it's returned value will be shown in the cell of grid.

```js
function formatMe(data){
    return data + " bla bla";
}

var grid = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: {
        data: createRandomData(50)
    },
    columns: [
        { field: "YourFieldName","template:"#= formatMe(data) #" }]
}).data("kendoGrid");
```

Comment: Thanks, I try your tip now. I did not think use a function inside #= #.

Comment: So, it is okay when I add a class in Columns fields like you propose. 
However, when I want to correct schema.model.fields.editable using the same process, this is not good. I think I will operate directly with the data-role="editable" ...

Comment: Sorry I'm too tired now (writing codes for 10Hrs). I think you should use [datasource object](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource) and bind it to your grid, then every time you edit or add or remove from your datasource it should be update the grid too automaticlly and also the `#= formatMe(data) #` will be called automaticlly.

Comment: I am not sure understanding the interest of datasource object. I think I have understood the solution you have described. Indeed, I have created a grid which has different class on a column, depending of the row and of the return of "#= formatMe(data) #". For the template it is good. After, when I want to choose if my cell should be editable or not, the same machinery does not work.
I hope I a clear, else I answer my current code.
Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I have found an alternative solution for this issue.

The variable "fige" is the variable allowing the edition when we select the cell.
Instead of using KendoUi, I have prefered make my own solution.

When I build "position" and "longueur" columns :

```
{
    field : "position",
    title : "Position",
    width : 70,
    template : "<span class='position#= index #' ><input style='width:70px' type='text' value='#= position#' #= readOnly(fige) # /></span>"
},{
    field : "longueur",
    title : "Longueur",
    width : 70,
    template : "<span class='longueur#= index #'><input style='width:70px' type='text' value='#= longueur#' #= readOnly(fige) # /></span>"
}
```

And the readOnly(fige) function :

```
function readOnly(fige)
{  
    if (fige == "true")
        return "readonly";
    else
        return ""; 
}
```

Dynamically, I obtain cells editable or not thanks to this function. Maybe it is not as nice as KendoUI default solution, but I do not think this particular function is possible thanks to KendoUI.